# How to get the values inside cell in order after moving columns

Tags: c#, winforms

Let me explain a bit better the question. I'm using windows forms (windows application)

I have a datagridview with X columns, example:

Example 1:

```
address 0 | address 1 | address 2 | address 3
value0    |   value1  |   value2  |   value3
```

Now, the problem is: i have the datagridview that let the user move columns just with the mouse, so the user can reorder the columns like he wants. Then i have to save all the values in the exact order that user has on the view after he ordered the columns.

Example 2

```
address 0 | address 3 | address 2 | address 1
value0    |   value3  |   value2  |   value1
```

So, from example 1 i should have:

listAddresses = [value0, value1, value2, value3]

From example 2 i should have:
listAddresses = [value0, value3, value2, value1]

But it seems like, after the user dragged a column, the datagrid view didn't change the index of the column moved.

Is there a way i can achieve this?

For now the code i'm using is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < addressTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    _journey.addresses[i] = 
 controllerAddress.GetByName(addressTable.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
}
```

In both example, with the code above, the result is:

listAddresses = [value0, value1, value2, value3]

Comment: winforms or asp.net?

Comment: You are right, my bad. Post updated. Windows Forms by the way.